# FFTW non-symetric inverse transform c2r

Tags: fft, fftw, ifft, asymmetric

Suppose I have a real 2D matrix `A(MxN)`, by using the FFTW3 `r2c` transform I take the matrix into Fourier space where `B` is the complex array `B=fft(A(Mx(N/2+1)))`.

I know that `B` has Hermetian redundancy, so I perform some operations (left-right, up-down flips and complex conjugates) to recover the Hermetian symmetry to obtain the full complex matrix `B'`.

Now I perform some operations on the full complex matrix `B'` (such that it is no longer symmetric and want to take the inverse using `c2r`, how do I do this since the `c2r` transform is now expecting a symmetric half matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `B'` is not symmetric, its inverse transform is not real. You cannot use `c2r` meaningfully on this matrix. Use the regular complex-to-complex inverse transform.